# MS Sql Server Object Creation / Alter Script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, system-tables

In Sql Server when you select to modify a SP or UDF it loads the objects alter query in a query window. Are these queries accessible in a system table so I can store the alter statements somewhere? It looks like syscomments has some objects but not all of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use syscomments**, because `syscomments.text` is `nvarchar(4000)` and as a result will truncate anything that is longer.

Use `sys.sql_modules` because `definition` is `nvarchar(max)`, it will not truncate long code.

use this to view the text of a given procedure, view, or function:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE object_id=object_id('YourProcedure')
```

Use this to get the name, type, and text of any procedure, view, or function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc, m.definition
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.object_id=object_id('CPT_SP_IRA_ComboBox_IncidentStatus')
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you can see stored procedures with the following query:

```
SELECT SO.Type,SO.Name,SC.Text
FROM sysobjects SO (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN syscomments SC (NOLOCK) on SO.Id = SC.ID
AND SO.Type = 'P'
ORDER BY SO.Name
```

If you're after different object types, take a look at  [sys.sysobjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx) for the different types.